# Lock Firebug to a specified page

Tags: firefox, firebug

Is there a way to keep Firebug on a single page, so that when I switch pages it remains on the page I want it set to?

For example, I'm working on a project and I get an error that I want to search for on Stack Overflow, but when I navigate here, the console changes to reflect this site. I'd like to stop that from happening.

Comment: To my knowledge Chrome's DevTools also do not offer the requested functionality, nor do any other developer tools. Vacuous messages like this don't help in any way.

Comment: chrome's debugger launches each instance in a separate window that is pinned to the page it was launched from thus achieving my desired functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to "pin" a page's data in Firebug (as of version 2.x). As far as I know this also doesn't work in any of the browser built-in dev tools.
Though the simple solution for your problem is to open the other page in a separate tab or window. Doing so keeps all the data of the page saved when you switch back to the tab containing your project's page.

Note that [Firebug's activation model](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Activation) is based on URLs following the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). I.e. if you open it for your project's page, it will always get opened for your projects page, even on other tabs, but not for any other site.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it useful to split the tab of interest off into a new window and to activate Firebug on that window. That way I can continue using my original tab collection/window without it changing as I link-hop.